# Why i cannot use package org.hibernate although i have added all file .jar from Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm using IntelliJ IDE to learn Java Web. In Hibernate, i'm trying configuration hibernate file by steps:

1. Copy all file .jar from the Hibernate's lib
2. Paste to folder lib in IntelliJ
3. Config file hibernate.cfg.xml
   but i have a trouble with org.hibernate.dialect ...

[image]

Comment: Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project). You should add libs to your classpath.

Comment: You should [avoid adding pictures of test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Thank SternK so much... i will try it.